# Erro ao dar build IONIC/PHONEGAP

Tags: osx, ionic, mac

Uso um Mac, tentei dar os comandos sudo ionic build ios / sudo ionic build android, porem, recebo o erro abaixo:

> Error: spawn EACCES
>       at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
>       at ChildProcess.spawn (child_process.js:1162:11)
>       at Object.exports.spawn (child_process.js:995:9)
>       at Object.exports.spawn (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:104:31)
>       at runScriptViaChildProcessSpawn (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/hooks/HooksRunner.js:188:23)
>       at runScript (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/hooks/HooksRunner.js:131:16)
>       at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/hooks/HooksRunner.js:114:20
>       at _fulfilled (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:787:54)
>       at self.promiseDispatch.done (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:816:30)
>       at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:749:13)

Answer (score 1):

Encontrei o erro, estava faltando o ANT e estava na API 22 nao na 21, apenas retirei a 22 e instalei a 21 e adicionei o ANT

Vlw